# How can I perform a click action on a button that is present on a child window using pywinauto?

Tags: python-3.x, button, click, pywinauto

I am able to perform a button click on the parent window but I am not sure how I can perform a click action on the button of a child window.

```
app = Application().connect(path=newPath) 
app.name_of_the_parent_window.draw_outline()
app.name_of_the_parent_window.print_control_identifiers()
app.name_of_the_parent_window.Button6.click()  #this click will open a new window with yes & no buttons.I would like to click on yes button but I am unable to do that

print(app.windows()[0].children(title_re=".*would you like to reset.*", class_name="Button")) #this prints the information about buttons
```

[image of the result of the above print command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16VqB.png)

I can see that Yes is a button. but I do not know of a way to perform click() on button yes

I tried the following command which failed with the error message 
[error mesage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/435wp.png)

Please let me know how can I perform a click action on the button of a child window.

Answer (score 0):

It returns a list of `ButtonWrapper`s. So you can choose, for example, the first button and call method `.click()` for it. This method is silent (mouse cursor is not moved), so another method `.click_input()` performs more realistic click.

```
app = Application().connect(path=newPath) 
app.name_of_the_parent_window.draw_outline()
app.name_of_the_parent_window.print_control_identifiers()
app.name_of_the_parent_window.Button6.click()  #this click will open a new window with yes & no buttons.I would like to click on yes button but I am unable to do that

buttons = app.windows()[0].children(title_re=".*would you like to reset.*", class_name="Button")
print(buttons) #this prints the information about buttons
buttons[0].click() # or buttons[0].click_input()
```

This is a quick fix for your code. More nice way it could look so:

```
app.name_of_the_parent_window.child_window(title="&Yes", class_name="Button").click()
```

If you want to print all possible `child_window` specifications, use method `.dump_tree()` for parent window specification:

```
app.name_of_the_parent_window.dump_tree()
```

To get wrapper object for the specification use method `.wrapper_object()`:

```
button_wrp = app.name_of_the_parent_window.child_window(title="&Yes", class_name="Button").wrapper_object()
```

Then you can type `button_wrp.` in IDE and see expanded list of available methods of the wrapper. Also it's easy to use `dir(button_wrp)`, it's a built-in Python function to get all attributes of any Python object (very useful for inspecting objects you're unfamiliar with).